# Как я могу анимировать bar charts используя clip-path?

Tags: css, html5, css-animation

У меня есть `bar chart`, на элементах которого  используется градиентный фон.

Высота градиента постоянна, и я применяю `clip path`, чтобы обрезать и показать только оставшуюся часть полосы.

Таким образом, самая темная часть всегда на высоте 100%
Проблема,  состоит в том, чтобы анимировать каждый `bar` от `0px` высоты до его заданной величины.

Сначала я попытался анимировать `clip-path`, используя анимацию, `transition` и `transform`. Но не получилось.

Затем я попытался анимировать сам `bar`  - и это вроде как работает. Только это идет сверху вниз, а не снизу вверх.  https://jsfiddle.net/ytvag42n/3/

Как я могу заставить бары расти снизу?

```css
.barChart { clear: both; height: 70px; width: 170px; border-bottom: solid 2px #eee;          }
    
    .bar {
      float: left;
      margin: 4px;
      width: 6px;
      background: linear-gradient(to top, #8BC2CA 0%, #2E92A0 100%);
      animation: expandBar 2s ease;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    
    .bar1 { clip-path: inset(80% 0 0 0 round 1.5px 1.5px 0px 0px); }
    .bar2 { clip-path: inset(20% 0 0 0 round 1.5px 1.5px 0px 0px); }
    .bar3 { clip-path: inset(60% 0 0 0 round 1.5px 1.5px 0px 0px); }
    .bar4 { clip-path: inset(80% 0 0 0 round 1.5px 1.5px 0px 0px); }
    .bar5 { clip-path: inset(20% 0 0 0 round 1.5px 1.5px 0px 0px); }
    .bar6 { clip-path: inset(60% 0 0 0 round 1.5px 1.5px 0px 0px); }
    .bar7 { clip-path: inset(80% 0 0 0 round 1.5px 1.5px 0px 0px); }
    .bar8 { clip-path: inset(20% 0 0 0 round 1.5px 1.5px 0px 0px); }
    .bar9 { clip-path: inset(60% 0 0 0 round 1.5px 1.5px 0px 0px); }
    
    @keyframes expandBar{
      0% {
        height: 0;
      }
      100%{
        height: 60px;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="barChart">
  <div class="bar bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar bar3"></div>
  <div class="bar bar4"></div>
  <div class="bar bar5"></div>
  <div class="bar bar6"></div>
  <div class="bar bar7"></div>
  <div class="bar bar8"></div>
  <div class="bar bar9"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/55022550/7394871

Comment: Мне эти `bar` (результат в вопросе всмысле), напоминают лого Cisco :) Есть что-то общее

Comment: о..., навел на мысль в одном моём задании, спасибо

Answer (score 4):

Вместо `clip-path` вы можете использовать высоту вашего элемента и фиксированный размер для вашего градиента. Тогда вы сможете легко анимировать прирост этой высоты.

Хитрость для анимации состоит в том, чтобы сделать элементы `inline-block` (вместо `float`) и иметь скрытую, (установленную с псевдоэлементом) высоту: `100%`, чтобы определить базовую линию внизу, и тогда ваш элемент сможет анимироваться снизу, а не сверху.

```css
.barChart {
  height: 70px;
  width: 170px;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #eee;
}
.barChart:before {
  content:"";
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
}
.bar {
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 4px;
  width: 6px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #8BC2CA 0, #2E92A0 70px); /*same as height:100%*/
  animation: expandBar 2s ease;
}

.bar1 {height: 80%;}
.bar2 {height: 20%;}
.bar3 {height: 60%;}
.bar4 {height: 70%;}
.bar5 {height: 50%;}

@keyframes expandBar {
  0% {
    height: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="barChart">
  <div class="bar bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar bar3"></div>
  <div class="bar bar4"></div>
  <div class="bar bar5"></div>
</div>
```

Если вам интересно, вы можете сделать это только с одним элементом и `multiple background`:

```css
.barChart {
  height: 70px;
  width: 170px;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #eee;
  --grad:linear-gradient(to top, #8BC2CA 0, #2E92A0 70px);
  background-image:var(--grad), var(--grad), var(--grad), var(--grad), var(--grad);
  background-size:6px 60%,6px 80%,6px 20%,6px 70%,6px 50%;
  background-position:4px 100%, 14px 100%, 26px 100%, 38px 100%,48px 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  animation: expandBar 2s ease;
}

@keyframes expandBar {
  0% {
    background-size: 6px 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="barChart">
</div>
```